# Extract digits from a long number in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to extract the digits from a number *n*, with:

00000000000 ≤ *n* ≤ 99999999999

using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int N;
    int power=1;


    scanf("%d",&N);

    while(N>power)
      power*=10;

    power/=10;

    while(N != 0)
    {
        int digit = N/power;
        printf("%d\n", digit);
        if(digit!=0)
          N=N-digit*power;
        if(power!=1)
          power/=10;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

It works well for a range of values, but for an 11 digit number, I get an error. Any tips on how to fix it to handle the *n* range?

Comment: The maximum int is 10 digits.

Comment: A 32-bit integer has a limit of about 2 billion (10 digits), so you'll need a 64-bit integer (`long long int` available on many platforms) to do this, but it will require adjustment in a bunch of things above to get  them all to agree.

Comment: If you enter the number as a string, you have its digits already there.